# Inversion count algorithm confusion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I just implemented an inversion count algorithm ( counts how many numbers are out of order ), where in-order is supposed to mean a sorted in ascending order array.

```
 Merge-and-Count(A,B):
    Maintain a Current pointer into each list, initialized to point to the front elements
    Maintain a variable Count for the number of inversions, initialized to 0
    While both lists are nonempty:
        Let a_i and b_j be the elements pointed to by the Current pointer 
        Append the smaller of these two to the output list 
        If b_j is the smaller element then:
            Increment Count by the number of elements remaining in A 
        Endif
        Advance the Current pointer in the list from which the smaller element was  selected.
    EndWhile
    Once one list is empty, append the remainder of the other list to the output
    Return Count and the merged list

countInversions(L):
    If the list has one element then:
        return 0
    Else
        Divide the list into two halves:
            A contains the first n/2 elements
            B contains the remaining n/2 elements
            (r_A, A) = countInversions(A)
            (r_B, B) = countInversions(B)
            (r, L) = Merge-and-Count(A,B)
    Endif
    Return r = r_A + r_B + r and the sorted list L
```

What is confusing me is this last line to return `r_A + r_B + r`. What I first thought is just return `r`, because this will give the number of inversions in the list (A, B), which is basically what we need. Why also add the number of inversions of the sublists, they will be included in r, won't they? Also, here is an example of what the algorithm does: For the list 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, it will find three inversions: (2,1), (4,1) and (4,3). P.S: I follow the explanations from Algorithm Design book by Jon Kleinberg, p 222.

Comment: I kinda messed the indentation, but countInversions is another function.

Comment: `r` is a number of inversions accounted while merging `A` and `B`, and they are _already sorted_. Returning just `r` would lose the inversions accounted while sorting `A` and `B`.

Comment: Oh, for real! Thanks man.